# Process JSON response in leaflet.GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, leaflet

I have a JSON response from a Django view that either returns valid geoJSON for web mapping or returns this `{"json": 0}`.

The code below handles both the valid geoJSON and also strangely the `{"json": 0}'`

```
var intersection = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("http://127.0.0.1:8000/intersection_data/", {
  style: color(intersection, "purple"),
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("Intersection")
  }
});

intersection.addTo(map);
```

it throws no error, so what I need is a way to not add the empty JSON to the map

```
$.ajax({url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/intersection_data"}).done(function(data){console.log(data.json);})
```

Comment: why don't you first fetch the data using an ajax call and then initialise your `L.GeoJSON` using the `L.GeoJSON(data, {options})` initiliazer?

Comment: okay and then what?

Comment: well if you do the ajax call yourself you can check the data and if data.json == 0 then not add the `intersection`.

Comment: okay I added my ajax call

Comment: that's not how $.ajax() works, you have to process the response in the .done() promise of the call.

Comment: Make sure you use the correct url, including the trailing `/`. Django by default responds with a http redirect if the slash is missing, and I'm not sure if `jQuery.ajax` automatically posts to the redirected url.

Comment: @HåkenLid its catching the correct URL

Comment: @dirkgroten I updated the question, is that what you meant? its still returning undefined

Comment: What do you expect this callback to do? Where do you get `data` from? It's not the data passed to the callback, because your callback takes no arguments.

Comment: No it’s `done(function(data){console.log(data);})` and you can remove `var data =`.

Comment: okay this is working...now should I include the if else logic inside the .done() or afterwards?